# Wordpress : Disable LayerSlider for mobile

Tags: wordpress

I am using the the7 theme on WordPress 3.1.8, with the LayerSlider plugin,and I wish the slider to be hidden or disabled only for mobile devices.
I already searched for an answer on the Web, but none of the solutions worked for me. Do you have any idea how I can manage it ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try this .. but this trick should work. Put below code in custom css of your theme.

```
  /* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.avia-layerslider {
display: none !important;
}
}
```

Or you can get idea from this to how to hide slider in mobile.If nothing is work than share your website link with me?

Comment: I already tried, but it doesn't work, even if I replace avia-layerslider by the actual class of the slider. Same with the slider's id.
Here is the website : http://www.proteogenix.science/

Comment: it seems it works better with #main-slideshow as an id, but this seems based on the viewport size rather on the media type, thought.  I guess it's ok but can we do something about the white space that repalce the slider ?

Comment: I browsed your website. layer slider is  not visible in mobile device but there is lot of space because of header height

Comment: Reduce height of masthead and remove top padding from #main in media query for only screen like                                                                                                              '@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.masthead{
height: 100px !important;
}                                                                                                                     #main{                                                                                                           padding-top:0px !important;                     }           
}'